# QuickGraph Serialization, custom Vertices and Edges

Tags: c#, serialization, quickgraph

my goal is to store a [BidirectionalGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BidirectionalGraph&referringTitle=Documentation).
Due to the fact that I process big data, a xml file is not usable. Unfortunately the program has to work without a database.
Therefore I need a way to serialize the graph memory- efficiently.
I tried .NET Serialization and GraphML Serialization.
But none of them worked.
Using .Net I get that error: "no implicit reference conversion..." due to the missing [Serializable] statement at BidirectionalGraph- class.
Using xmlwriters I get a System.NotSupportedException: "Property type MyEdge.Source not supported by the GraphML schema&quot"
I already marked my custom vertex class and edge class serializable.
The **EdgeClass** implements IEdge and has two additional int attributes.
The **VertexClass** has int attributes as well as a dictionary and a list.

Maybe someone can help me make BidirectionalGraph serializable or got another solution?
Thank you for your help in this matter.